# Encapsulating an object and a reference that uses its lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime

I’m working with a Rust library that uses references to provide access to child objects (the library is `zip`, but I’ve had this come up in other contexts as well). Its usage pattern is as follows:

1. Call `Foo::new(arg1: A) -> Foo` to get a Foo.
2. Call `Foo.member<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a Bar<'a>` to get a Bar, and use it.

Now, I want to write a convenience function that takes `arg1` and returns `Bar`, or an object encapsulating `Bar` (it’s easy to implement and delegate the relevant traits of `Bar`.

This seems to be a prime use case for the nonexistent `'self` lifetime.

Is there a good, safe, Rustic way to do this encapsulation? The best I’ve been able to come up with uses a bit of unsafe: put `Foo` in a box, leak it, save its pointer (along with the `Bar` reference) in an encapsulating struct, and implement `Drop` to re-box and drop `Foo`.

Comment: are these valid single quotes, or is this a display shenanigan?

Comment: It is not clear to me what the *convenience function* is and what is its relation with `Foo`.

Comment: This sounds like a classic self-referential struct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier No, those are U+2018. It hurts my eyes.

Comment: @mkayaalp same.

Comment: @netwave I have cleaned up the arguments to try to make it clearer.

Comment: From some of the answers to the question linked by @kmdreko, the [`owning_ref`](https://docs.rs/owning_ref/) package seems to be a good encapsulated solution to this problem. Under the hood, it uses raw pointers, but wraps this up in a safe API.